# Change the key of first arrays in three dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

The following code gives the array below, however I need it formatted differently (stated after the array), so it will work for a javascript function I've already written.

```
$sql = "SELECT towhich, duedate, amount FROM sales WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY duedate ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$dbarray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dbarray[] = $row;
}


$graph = array();
$cnt = 0;
foreach($dbarray as $key => $values){
$orderdate = explode('-', $values['duedate']);
$month = $orderdate[1];
$graph[$month][$cnt] = array (
0 => $values['amount'],
1 => $values['towhich']
);
$cnt ++;
}

 //Now it's grouped by date
```

Array output:

```
array(5) 
{ 
        ["02"]=> array(2) 
              { 
                  [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" } 
                  [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "30" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" } 
              }
        ["03"]=> array(1) 
              { 
                  [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "50" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" } 
              } 
        ["04"]=> array(1) 
              {
                  [3]=> array(2) {[0]=> string(2) "40" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" }
              } 
        ["05"]=> array(2) 
              { 
                  [4]=> array(2) {[0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" } 
                  [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" } 
               }
        ["06"]=> array(1) 
               { 
                  [6]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(9) "the co op" }
               } 
}
```

The key index value for array should not be, for example, ['02'], but, being the first in the containing array, [0], like normal; and '03' should be [1].

I've looked around a lot, indeed it helped with what bit of code I've produced, however all answers seem to deal with changing the key value further inside the large array.  I'm new with multidimensional arrays, btw.  Thanks in advance.

In case you're wondering why I've done it like so, so far, it's because each first array should correspond to a different month; that's why I've ordered by date and all that.

Comment: `$graph = array_values($graph);`

Comment: _and '03' should be [1]._ isn't clear. Do you want the value '03' as part of each array that contains amount and towhich?

Comment: No, 03 corresponds to the first row of sub-rows, and not, sub-subarrays, i.e. where amount and towhich are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you can use: [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) :

```
$graph = array_values($graph);
```

so "02" will be 0, "03" will be 1 , ... etc.

Comment: Yeah, i didn't realise it was so easy; thanks a lot; that was it.  I thought it would involve foreach loops and everything lol.  cheers

Comment: Any idea how I can make the sub-subarray key 0,1 etc.  This is so at present for first array; however second subsubarray is 2, third subsubarray is 3 etc.

Comment: remove $cnt from index of $graph so th setting line will be: `$graph[$month][] = array (...`

Answer (score 0):

$key in your foreach will be the relative record number that the row occurs in the query.

```
$graph = array();
$cnt = 0;
foreach($dbarray as $key => $values){
    $orderdate = explode('-', $values['duedate']);
    $month = $orderdate[1];
    $graph[$month][$cnt] = array (
    $graph[$key] = array (
        $month,
        $values['amount'],
        $values['towhich']
    );
    $cnt ++;
}
```